# ROS and OpenCV: How can I convert a subscribed compressed image directly to OpenCV, and get new frame updates without using the video capture function

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, streaming, ros

Context:

I am trying to process an image stream with a gesture recognition algorithm using ROS, OpenCV and Python. All the examples I've seen use OpenCV .cap directly from a webcam to process video, whereas I am inserting an image stream with a known image that updates at around 40fps.

Using a typical ROS2 image subscriber node, I convert a compressed image message that I'm sending to the device via a camera.

Then, I pass through the compressed image as an argument into my gesture recognition script. Once I do this, my code seems to get 'stuck' and the image data goes dark. I suspect it's because I've modified the while loop within my gesture recognition to try to accommodate new frames, except I know no way of reading in new frames to the gesture recognizer.

Please could anyone suggest any means of achieving my goal? (passing the compressed_img_msg straight into opencv video processing and getting frame by frame updates still without using build in video functionality)?

See code for ROS2 image node and gesture recognition main below:

My ROS2 compressed_image node is below:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                                compressed_image node 

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class CompressedImageSubscriber(Node):
    def __init__(self, topic):
        super().__init__("image_view_sub_node")
        qos_policy = rclpy.qos.QoSProfile(reliability=rclpy.qos.ReliabilityPolicy.BEST_EFFORT,
                                          history=rclpy.qos.HistoryPolicy.KEEP_LAST,
                                          depth=1)
        self.sub = self.create_subscription(CompressedImage, topic,
                                            self.subscriber_callback, qos_profile=qos_policy)
        self.received_msg = False

    def subscriber_callback(self, compressed_image_msg):
        if self.received_msg == False:
            print("Image Data Received... Displaying Image in CV2 window")
            self.received_msg = True
            #this is the unprocessed image decoded from Unity 
        subscribed_image = CvBridge().compressed_imgmsg_to_cv2(compressed_image_msg, desired_encoding="bgr8")
        cv2.imshow("CompressedImage", subscribed_image)
        #pass the unprocessed image into the gesture recognition app
        
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        gesture_app.main(subscribed_image)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
#call the gesture script, pass throuigh image as an argument here 

#main code

def main():
    rclpy.init()

    topic_name = input("what is the topic name?: ")
    my_sub = CompressedImageSubscriber(topic_name)
    print("Waiting for data to be publisher over topic...")

    try:
        rclpy.spin(my_sub)
        
        
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        my_sub.destroy_node()
        rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

As you can see, once the image is decoded I pass through it to the gesture algorithm as an argument. The main script for this can be seen below: 

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                            GESTURE RECOGNITION MAIN FUNCTION 
       (source code: https://github.com/kinivi/hand-gesture-recognition-mediapipe)

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

def main(subscribed_image):
    # Argument parsing #################################################################
    args = get_args()

    cap_device = args.device
    cap_width = args.width
    cap_height = args.height

    use_static_image_mode = args.use_static_image_mode
    min_detection_confidence = args.min_detection_confidence
    min_tracking_confidence = args.min_tracking_confidence

    use_brect = True

    # Model load #############################################################
    mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands
    hands = mp_hands.Hands(
        static_image_mode=use_static_image_mode,
        max_num_hands=1,
        min_detection_confidence=min_detection_confidence,
        min_tracking_confidence=min_tracking_confidence,
    )

    keypoint_classifier = KeyPointClassifier()

    point_history_classifier = PointHistoryClassifier()

    # Read labels ###########################################################
    with open('model/keypoint_classifier/keypoint_classifier_label.csv',
              encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        keypoint_classifier_labels = csv.reader(f)
        keypoint_classifier_labels = [
            row[0] for row in keypoint_classifier_labels
        ]
    with open(
            'model/point_history_classifier/point_history_classifier_label.csv',
            encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        point_history_classifier_labels = csv.reader(f)
        point_history_classifier_labels = [
            row[0] for row in point_history_classifier_labels
        ]

    # FPS Measurement ########################################################
    cvFpsCalc = CvFpsCalc(buffer_len=10)

    # Coordinate history #################################################################
    history_length = 16
    point_history = deque(maxlen=history_length)

    # Finger gesture history ################################################
    finger_gesture_history = deque(maxlen=history_length)

    #  ########################################################################
    mode = 0

# Camera preparation ###############################################################
    #cap = subscribed_image
    
    cap = subscribed_image

#   cap = cv.VideoCapture()


    while True:
        fps = cvFpsCalc.get()

        # Process Key (ESC: end) #################################################
        key = cv.waitKey(10)
        if key == 27:  # ESC
            break
        number, mode = select_mode(key, mode)

        # Camera capture #####################################################
        
        image = cap
        if image is None:
            break

        image = cv.flip(image, 1)  # Mirror display
        debug_image = copy.deepcopy(image)

        # Detection implementation #############################################################
        image = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        image.flags.writeable = False
        results = hands.process(image)
        image.flags.writeable = True

            #  ####################################################################
        if results.multi_hand_landmarks is not None:
            for hand_landmarks, handedness in zip(results.multi_hand_landmarks,
                                                results.multi_handedness):
                # Bounding box calculation
                brect = calc_bounding_rect(debug_image, hand_landmarks)
                # Landmark calculation
                landmark_list = calc_landmark_list(debug_image, hand_landmarks)

                # Conversion to relative coordinates / normalized coordinates
                pre_processed_landmark_list = pre_process_landmark(
                    landmark_list)
                pre_processed_point_history_list = pre_process_point_history(
                    debug_image, point_history)
                # Write to the dataset file
                logging_csv(number, mode, pre_processed_landmark_list,
                            pre_processed_point_history_list)

                # Hand sign classification
                hand_sign_id = keypoint_classifier(pre_processed_landmark_list)
                if hand_sign_id == 2:  # Point gesture
                    point_history.append(landmark_list[8])
                else:
                    point_history.append([0, 0])

                # Finger gesture classification
                finger_gesture_id = 0
                point_history_len = len(pre_processed_point_history_list)
                if point_history_len == (history_length * 2):
                    finger_gesture_id = point_history_classifier(
                        pre_processed_point_history_list)

                # Calculates the gesture IDs in the latest detection
                finger_gesture_history.append(finger_gesture_id)
                most_common_fg_id = Counter(
                    finger_gesture_history).most_common()

                # Drawing part
                debug_image = draw_bounding_rect(use_brect, debug_image, brect)
                debug_image = draw_landmarks(debug_image, landmark_list)
                debug_image = draw_info_text(
                    debug_image,
                    brect,
                    handedness,
                    keypoint_classifier_labels[hand_sign_id],
                    point_history_classifier_labels[most_common_fg_id[0][0]],
                )
        else:
            point_history.append([0, 0])

        debug_image = draw_point_history(debug_image, point_history)
        debug_image = draw_info(debug_image, fps, mode, number)

        # Screen reflection #############################################################
        cv.imshow('Hand Gesture Recognition', debug_image)
        t = 1
        
        blank_image = np.zeros(shape=[512, 512, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
        image = blank_image

    
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Please could anyone advise, or have any ideas to another means of achieving this?

Comment: next time put code in ```   ``` or select code and use `Ctrl+K`

Comment: I can't run it but I think you shouldn't use `while True` in `gesture_app.main` because it blocks all code. You process image only once in `gesture_app.main` when you get new image in `subscriber_callback`. OR `subscriber_callback` should assign image to global variable (without running `gesture_app.main`) and you should run `gesture_app.main` (with `while True`) in separated `thread` and inside `while True` get image from global variable.

Comment: @furas your second suggestion is correct. They are trying to use two nodes nodes on top of each other, which doesn’t work. The callback should assign a global var that `gesture_app.main` uses. No need to spawn extra threads that way.

Comment: Thanks guys - I haven't tried that suggestion with Global var, but I removed the while true loop and it worked, but didn't perform greatly. Will try the global var later as that makes more sense.